# Can I use file choice dialog when saving files?

Tags: java, swing

How do I display and use a file choice dialog when I wish to save files from a Swing application?

Comment: What exactly is a Microsoft output menu?

Comment: When using Word, I want to save a file. It will pop up a window let me select where I want to save.  Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You are searching for `JFileChooser` then... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: I tried to improve your question a bit. Please let me know if I made any changes that you don't agree with. I think that your main problem with this question, and with your overall problem is that you did not know what words to choose when searching for this functionality, and also when asking this question. Don't worry, this skill will get better with time and effort.

Comment: It's okay. That is my disadvantage. Thanks for your encouragement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean a file chooser so try this :

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
// do what ever you wanted to do with the file
```

Comment: umm...  I think I ask a very stupid problem...

Comment: What's bad is to not ask about what you do not now ... although you should've done some research yourself first and showed some effort ;)